# $u_{xx} + u_{xy} + u_{yy} = 0$ in canonical form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, canonical-transformation

How do i put $u_{xx} + u_{xy} + u_{yy} = 0$ in canonical form?

$a=1, b=1/2, c=1 $ implies that it is elliptic as $b^2 - ac <0$

$dy/dx = \lambda$ where $a\lambda^2-2b\lambda+c=0$ gives $\lambda = \pm\sqrt{\frac{-3}{4}} + 1/2$

As these roots are complex I am not sure how to proceed?

Can i take $ξ=y-x$ and $η=x$ to give me $u_{ξξ} + u_{ηη} - u_{ηξ} =0$ which is in canonical form?

Answer (score 0):

$\lambda_1=\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2},\ \lambda_2=\overline{\lambda_1}=\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
\implies \varepsilon=y-\lambda_1x, \ \eta=y-\overline{\lambda_1}x$

The standard procedure to deal with complex roots involves finding the canonical form by making the substitution $\alpha=\frac{\varepsilon+\eta}{2}=y-\frac{\lambda_1+\overline\lambda_1}{2}x=y-Re(\lambda_1)x,\ \beta=\frac{\eta-\varepsilon}{2i}=\frac{\lambda_1-\bar\lambda_1}{2i}x=Im(\lambda_1)x$.

The canonical form so obtained will not contain complex constants.

Comment: Can i take $ξ=y-x$ and $η=x$ to give me $u_{ξξ} + u_{ηη} - u_{ηξ} =0$ which is in canonical form?

Comment: This is not in canonical form. It involves all the second order partial derivatives of $u$, whilst the aim of reducing an equation to its canonical form is to remove such derivatives to make the analysis of the partial differential equation easier. The equation you got is not very different from the original equation.

Comment: using your method i still get second order partials of u, i cant seem to get it into canonical form?

Comment: You may not be able to remove all the second order partial derivatives. The canonical forms of parabolic and hyperbolic equations also contain second order partial derivatives. The point is to be able to remove at least some of them. Do you still get 3 second order partial derivatives?

Comment: no, i get 2: $u_{αα} + u_{ββ} = 0$

thanks

Comment: You're welcome.